# What is the word for "demand something without saying it"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

What is the word/expression/phrase/idiom for "demand something without saying it"?

For instance, if my father expects me to "show" respect by standing up when he walks into the room, I could say - My father ______________ (demand without saying it) respect. He will not say that I have to stand up, but he will be passive-aggressive if I don't show respect.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a word to mean _silently expect_. _Expects_ can fill the blank but expectations can be vocal too.

Comment: He *commands* respect? "3 [with object] Be in a strong enough position to have or secure. ... ‘he commanded considerable personal loyalty’" ODO https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/command

Comment: "b :  to demand or receive as one's due " MW https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/command

Comment: @alwayslearning: I would favor "implicitly expects" over "silently expects".

Comment: @Kris I think that's worth an answer...

Answer (score 2):

The person in question has a *sense of **entitlement***. See the ODO example below which talks of someone's anger *indirectly* expressing their sense of entitlement. For the sample sentence, we can use the verb form ***entitle*** (*entitled to*).

> My father *feels **entitled to*** respect.

ODO:

> **[entitlement](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entitlement)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.2** The belief that one is inherently deserving of privileges or special treatment.
>
> ‘His anger might also have betrayed his sense of entitlement.’
>
> **[entitle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entitle)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** (*often **be entitled to***) Give (someone) a legal right or a just claim to receive or do something.
>
> ‘Every natural and legal person is entitled to the peaceful enjoyment
>   of his possessions.’